# Javascript runtime not included in default Gemfile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 3.2.9 and ruby 1.9.3

When I do a

```
rails new blog
```

and try to generate a controller

```
rails g controller auth
```

it always throws an error :

```
 Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

and I always go back and edit the Gemfile with rubyracer gem( or one of the javascript runtimes available at [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs).
Why is one of the  javascript runtimes not included as a default gem in the Gemfile generated initially? Is there a specific reason to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the js-runtime installed wide-system. For example, if you install node.js in linux, you will have js-runtime and there is no need to add anything to your Gemfile